# how to clone git repository with submodules without asking for password for every subrepository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm recently put a repository into bitbucket. And this repository has some submodules

I'm working on a Initialization script. I would like to clone the main directory and them pull all subdirectories.

```
 git clone https://bitbucket.org/#####/main.git elastic --recurse-submodules
```

this prompts me for the user and password.

```
Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': myuser 
Password for 'https://myuser@bitbucket.org':
```

and them it asks me again for every submodule

```
Username for 'https://bitbucket.org':  
...
```

My .gitmodules file is like:

```
[submodule "api"]
     path = app/api/
     url = git@bitbucket.org/###/api.git
     branch = master
[submodule "front"]
     path = app/front
     url = git@bitbucket.org/###/front.git
     branch = master
[submodule "app/config"]
     path = app/config
     url = git@bitbucket.org/###/config.git
     branch = master

... some few more repositories
```

How can I clone the main repository and them use the same credentials to all childs repositories?

I'm using AWS AMI Linux.

Comment: aren't you using SSH directly for this? Check https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Comment: See [Caching your GitHub password in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-windows). It's not specific to Github.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting up the git to use the credential memory cache solves my problem

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

this is enough to pull all repos with the same user/password

If i want to keep the same cache for a entire day, I'm able to set the time for a longer timespan:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=86400'
```

86400 seconds = 1 day;

Answer (score 0):

Check your git config output:

type: `git config -l`

If you see a rule like:

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git@github.com/
```

That would explain why credentials for an HTTPS URL are used even for submodules.